# Android buttons - difference in listener

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I'm new to android development and I see there are 2 different ways to make a button perform a specific task.

The 1st way is to have a `setOnClickListener()` within your onCreate function.

The 2nd is to create a separate method in its Activity page and call it using the activity's XML using `android:onClick="thisFunction"`

I have always found it easier to call functions using android:onClick in the XML.

Would this way make the buttons perform slower?
When would you experts prefer one way over another?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, it's always better to set the onClick in the code, since the xml way only works well with activities. When you try to do that with fragments, it will ask you to choose an activity to handle the onClick() from the xml. Imagine having a single activity app, with lots of fragments, and having all of it's onClick() methods spread across the MainActivity code. It's quite a mess.

Regarding performance `setOnClickListener()` vs `onClick() inside xml`, I think it's pretty much the same nowadays.

Comment: I wouldn't advise using Butterknife. That's a tool from a time long ago, and if you visit their Github the first thing they mention is that the tool has been deprecated... What I'd rather advise is using Kotlin view extensions and Android View Binding (https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

Comment: Wow, you're right. I will edit my answer. Thank you for the heads up @Hayuki